# Does google authenticator supports time step more than 30sec?

Tags: linux, openldap, google, otp

I have generated a QR from here https://freeotp.github.io/qrcode.html defining a time period of 60sec and while scanning QR-Code through google authenticator app it uses the default time step of only 30seconds.

Does google authenticator support a time step of more than 30sec? If not why? How can I make it to support it?

Comment: from your link, [OTP Key URI Format](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/wiki/Key-Uri-Format), it says """Currently, the period parameter is ignored by the Google Authenticator implementations.""" ... if so, it's apparently not possible with google authenticator for now.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out.